# Is there a name for the inverses of the functions (i.e for the left-unique, right-total binary relations)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, terminology, relations

The right-unique, left-total binary relations are the functions, while the  left-unique, right-total ones are their inverses. So, they are the morphisms of $\mathsf{Set}^\mathrm{op}$. Do they have a name too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no name for these more fundamental than the two you already gave, unless you view $\mathbf{Set}^\mathrm{op}$ as the category of powersets and call them homomorphisms!